# How can I find Yahoo membersince now that the YQL interface has been changed?

Tags: yql

I was using the following to get various Yahoo account info on myself. When people wanted to know when they joined Yahoo I would give this link. Is there a replacement since it no longer works?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?_uiFocus=answers&q=select%20*%20from%20answers.getbycategory%20where%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22#h=select+*+from+social.profile+where+guid%3Dme

Comment: YQL no longer includes 'console' in the URL so it would look something like  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/?_uiFocus=answers&q=select * from answers.getbycategory where category_id=2115500137 and type='resolved'#h=select * from social.profile where guid=me

Comment: However, when I try your query in the console (directly by cut and paste) it is throwing an authentication error.